# How to add entity framework core to a class library(.net core)

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I created a Class library(.net Core) and I'm trying to add an entity framework model but I received the following message

[image]

Would anyone tell me what I miss ?

Comment: I'm trying to add entityframe work database first .emx template file to a class library .net core

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add a EF6 model to a .NET Core project, you must use EF Core code first/scaffoling. Start by adding th Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Nuget package

Comment: Do you have to use code first? Is there not database first option in core? If that is the case Core is off my christmas card list!